# Passing props to parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to use a value that is generated within a function in child.js and pass this to parent.js so I can use this value to filter the array of children.

**Child.js**

```
const returnDistance = () => {
            const dist = getDistance(userLat, userLng, lat, lng).toFixed(1);
            this.props.onCalculateDistance(dist);
            return dist;
        }
```

`return dist` is the value that is generated that I need to access within parent.js

**Parent.js**

```
// The callback function
    distanceChange = (dist) => {
            console.log(dist)
            return dist;
    }

//The map to render child.js data. Im passing distanceChange as a prop.
{filteredResults.filter(({ node }) => (node.onCalculateDistance >= 0)).map(({ node }) => {
    return (
        <SpaceWrapper key={node.id}>
            <Space node={node} onCalculateDistance={this.distanceChange} />
        </SpaceWrapper>
    )
}
)}
```

Am I missing something glaringly obvious here? The console.log for `distanceChange` returns all of the values for the child.js nodes but returns undefined when used as a prop.

How do I get the function to run so I can filter the results with the returned value?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with below code , Do you want to check the node.dist?  `node.onCalculateDistance >= 0`

Comment: So that's just a verbose example but I'm attempting to filter out results that will be greater than 5 for instance, but I'm getting confused somewhere and can't work out how to get the actual value from the function within the child.

Comment: Can you add your code to codesandbox.

Comment: The short answer is: you don't. Props *by definition* are passed to the child and the child cannot mutate. It is very unclear what the actual relationship of these items is in the code. It seems to be complicated by the `node` being passed around, so that needs to be elucidated. The fact that you're using a code generator may be complicating the issue, adding "non-beginner" code that makes editing and understanding the result harder.

Comment: It's also not clear why `parent` needs `dist`. When you write "filter the array of children" are you talking about a different type of child component than `child` above? Also missing from your `parent` code examples is any notion of **state**.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you're doing is returning a value and not doing anything with it. For the parent to store the value of `dist` it needs to have that property.

What you need to do is add the property `dist` to the parent, and then define `getDistance` in the parent as well. You can then pass `getDistance` to the child, and the child can call that function to update the parent `this.state.dist` property.

So for example you could have

**parent.js**

```
return (
    <SpaceWrapper key={node.id}>
        <Space node={node} getDistance={this.getDistance} />
    </SpaceWrapper>
)
```

Then in the child you can call `this.props.getDistance()` to update

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but still seems to be getting `undefined` for `this.dist` 

`<Space dist={this.dist} node={node} userLat={this.state.userLat} userLng={this.state.userLng} />`

Comment: is `this.dist` defined in the parent class? Actually should be `this.state.dist` sorry. You need to set `dist` property on parent state

Comment: This doesn't sound right. A child component should never attempt to mutate the props passed to it. OP has the right idea, he's just missing a couple things.

Comment: @MarcL. you're right... its been a while since Ive been in react, but I just updated my answer. I think this is the right solution.